# What is the significance order of this Verilog initialization syntax?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This is a simple SystemVerilog question that I am having a surprisingly difficult time finding the answer for.

In this kind of bit array initialization syntax, is the b[0] part assigned to a's most significant bit, or the least significant bit?

```
bit a[7:0];
bit b[7:0] = 8'hff;
bit c[7:0] = 8'h00;

a = {b[0], c[6:0]};
```

So does a[0] == 1 or a[7] == 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you've found it hard to find an answer is because the result is dependent on how you've declared things.

You've declared `a` to be `[7:0]`. Therefore the bits in `a` are arranged like this:

```
a7 a6 a5 a4 a3 a2 a1 a0
```

You then assign `{b[0], c[6:0}` to `a`:

```
a7 a6 a5 a4 a3 a2 a1 a0 = b0 c6 c5 c4 c3 c2 c1 c0
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 =  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

`A[7] == 1`

If you'd declared `a` to be `[0:7]` the result would have been:

```
a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 = b0 c6 c5 c4 c3 c2 c1 c0
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 =  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

`A[0] == 1`

Answer (score 3):

`b[0]` is assigned to the most significant bit, `a[7]`; i.e. `a[7] == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

However, I'm not sure it's typo or your intention to use unpacked declaration. `bit a[7:0]` is an `unpacked array`, it does not mean continuous storage and it can not be directly assigned packed or integral value.

Following is adopted from `SystemVerilog for Design`, P.114, 5.3.1 Unpacked arrays

> Unpacked array stores each element independently, but grouped under a common array name.

P.122, 5.3.5 Assigning values to arrays

> SystemVerilog extends Verilog with two additional ways to assign values to unpacked arrays:
>     - The entire array can be assigned a list of values
>     - A slice of the array can be assigned a list of values.
>
> The list of values is specified between '{ } braces, the same as with initializing unpacked  arrays.

For packed array, `bit [7:0] a`, we do have correct answer from Paul.

Comment: I simplified it from the source file I am actually looking at. I am looking at a few bit arrays defined as part of a packed struct. If a struct is packed, will that in turn mean its bit arrays are packed?

Comment: Yes. packed struct can only have integral or packed type as its fields.

Comment: Good catch, I'd missed that it was an unpacked array.